# Riesz potential inequality

Tags: potential-theory

Assume that $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbf{R}^n$ with the same area as a ball $B(x,r)$ and let $\alpha\in[1,0)$. I need the reference for the following inequality $$\int_{\Omega} |x-y|^{\alpha-n} dy\le \int_{B(x,r)} |x-y|^{\alpha-n} dy.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{\Omega}|x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy$$
$$=\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)}|x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy+\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)^c}|x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy$$
$$\leq\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)} |x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy+\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)^c}|r|^{\alpha-n}dy$$
$$=\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)} |x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy+\int_{\Omega^c\cap B(x,r)}|r|^{\alpha-n}dy$$
$$\leq\int_{\Omega\cap B(x,r)} |x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy+\int_{\Omega^c\cap B(x,r)}|x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy$$
$$=\int_{B(x,r)} |x-y|^{\alpha-n}dy$$

> **Attention** The second equality is by the same area.